# Does the order of the fields in the WHERE clause affect the performance?

Tags: mysql

for example: if there are two WHERE clause： WHERE stringA="value" AND intB=1.

Comment: No.  Even if it did, the query optimizer is responsible for picking the best execution plan.

Comment: It can, will depend on the database etc. I wouldn't worry about it until you see a query that is slow. Then you can play with explain plans to see if there is a difference, and dig deeper.  Some examples of differences may be due to indexs or how small a given where filters down your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a simple query like that, no. MySQL will attempt to process the most restrictive filters in priority order, taking any indexes into account.

When you get into complex queries that joins or nested selects, there can be a real art to how you place the query conditions to best restrict the number of rows that need to be joined.